# What are the limits of using a third-party framework to build a community?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-community

I have a client who wants a super custom looking Lightning Community. I know two options to build it are with Visualforce and Lightning Components.

I tried using Lightning Components, but was met with frustration because of `app.css`, a stylesheet that that Salesforce forces you to use when you are working with Lightning Components. `app.css` was affecting all the styles from html/css handed off to me to convert to a Lightning Component.

I know Visualforce you can have super custom UIs. I'm hesitant to use it though because it is an older way of building apps on the platform.

I have in the past created a web app using a third-party framework and hosted it in a Visualforce page. My worries about going down this route is I'm unsure of the limits of using a third-party framework to build a community on.

What are the limits of using a third-party framework to build a community? Is it even possible?

Comment: Visualforce is going to continue to be supported for a very long time. I wouldn't worry about not being able to use it. That being said, the lightning community builder probably is the right way to go. If you have issues with your CSS being applied to too many elements you can always wrap your components in a container div and use that as a starting point for all the elements within the component.

Comment: @gNerb I have issues with Salesforce's css being applied to my elements.

Comment: That should be easy enough for you to fight through though. There are rules in CSS that determine which styles "win". Generally using inline styles is a good way to take control. Otherwise you can be extremely specific with your style definitions or use the !important flag (last resort) to take control back. SF is infamous for being overly specific with their tags and CSS prioritizes the most specific css. This is also a problem that you could very well run into using VF. Also stay away from commonly used classes like .btn

Comment: but when I use, say the ui:button, it automatically applies css classes to it (SLDS). I don't see a way to avoid that styling.

Comment: View the rendered component, right click the button and inspect it, get a look at what classes and css are being used and override them in your CSS. I believe there's a site that you can also use to see the generated HTML of the components https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/

Comment: For instance UI button appears to use slds-button class. So if you override this style in your stylesheet you can change the look: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/

Comment: @gNerb but my stylesheet doesn't have a class on the button tag. How can I override a class from app.css if my current stylesheet has no class on the button tag, but app.css puts 4 class on the button tag?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm